# Struts namespaces and WEB-INF folder

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts2

I want to put `view.jsp` file in WEB-INF folder. it lies in `WEB-INF\user\view.jsp`

```
<package name="user" extends="struts-default"  namespace="user">
     <action name="view" class="com.example.user.ViewUserAction">
             <result>/WEB-INF/user/view.jsp</result>
     </action>
</package>
```

but Struts changes this url to `application/user/WEB-INF/user/view.jsp`

so as I understand if my namespace is not `"/"` I will never visit the JSP in `WEB-INF` ?

Comment: What? Where do you see that *Struts changes this url to application/user/WEB-INF/user/view.jsp* ?

Comment: A namespace is not a path to your action, it's like a placeholder where your action is resided.

Comment: @RomanC so it works like location from which action will be done ?

Comment: The location is what in the body of the result tag, and it's absolute in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where I was wrong.

As **Alexander M** pointed out in comments no such url will be generated.

The thing is I've tried various bad solutions, but most of them had the next synopsis.

In `struts.xml` I wrote:

```
<package name="product" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="view" class="com.example.action.product.ViewProduct">
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/view/product/view.jsp</result>
        </action>
</package>
```

and in jsp I refer to somee action as:

```
<a href="product/view">View product</a>
```

but seems like its wrong way to do it - in my case I had urls like:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/product/product/view.action
```

which is not valid.

So I changed struts.xml namespace to:

```
  <package name="product" namespace="/product" extends="struts-default">
            <action name="view" class="com.example.action.product.ViewProduct">
                <result name="success">/WEB-INF/view/product/view.jsp</result>
            </action>
   </package>
```

And then in `view.jsp` used struts `<s:a>` tag (*or you may use `<s:url>`*):

```
<a href="<s:url action='view' namespace="/product"/>"> View product</a>

<s:a action="view" namespace="/product"> View product</s:a>
```

For further reference about packages and namespaces understanding:

1. [Struts Namespace Configuration](https://struts.apache.org/docs/namespace-configuration.html)
2. [Struts Package Configuration](https://struts.apache.org/docs/package-configuration.html)

Comment: Yes, using S2 tags for url construction is the best practice.